# Make custom class compatible with `.join()`

Tags: python, string

I have a `StringPlus` class that represents a string with extra data. I'd like to make it compatible with `.join()` which is used inside a library that I feed a `StringPlus` list into. I have no control over the `join()` call. Simply defining `__str__()` doesn't work:

```py
class StringPlus:
    def __init__(self, string: str, extra_data):
        self._string = string
        self._extra_data = extra_data

    def __str__(self):
        return self._string


a = StringPlus("a", [1, 2, 3])

b = "".join([a, "b"])
assert b == "ab"
```

Any hints?

Comment: how about joining without resorting to external `join` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inherit `str`:

```
>>> class StringPlus(str):
...     def __init__(self, string=''):
...         self._extra_data = [1, 2, 3]
...
>>> "".join([StringPlus("a"), "b"])
'ab'
```

If you need to customize the construction parameters, you also need to overload the `__new__` method (note that the parameters in the `__new__` and `__init__` methods should be consistent):

```
>>> class StringPlus(str):
...     def __new__(cls, string, extra_data):
...        return super().__new__(cls, string)
...     def __init__(self, string, extra_data):
...        self._extra_data = extra_data
...
>>> "".join([StringPlus("a", [1, 2, 3]), "b"])
'ab'
```

Or just define the `__new__` method:

```
>>> class StringPlus(str):
...     def __new__(cls, string, extra_data):
...        self = super().__new__(cls, string)
...        self._extra_data = extra_data
...        return self
...
```

Answer (score 2):

`str.join` must be passed an iterable of strings, so this cannot be done without converting each element in the `list`.

```py
"".join(map(str, [a, "b"])) 
# or
"".join(str(x) for x in [a, "b"])
```

However, changing the class definiton to subclass `str` can allow this to work without manual conversion.

```py
class StringPlus(str):
```

Comment: Not an option since I have no access to the library that `join`s.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer Then you can try subclassing `str`.

Comment: That's probably the solution. I remember having had problems with that though. Let me play around with it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can equip your custom `StringPlus` class with `join` method to behave like/similar `str.join`:

```
class StringPlus:
    def __init__(self, string: str):
        self._string = string
        self._extra_data = [1, 2, 3]

    def join(self, args, sep=""):
        return sep.join([self._string, *args])

    def __str__(self):
        return self._string


a = StringPlus("a")

bc = a.join(["b", "c"], sep="")
assert bc == "abc"
```